# Do you know any good code sample of Web3j with Android?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, android

Do you have any good code sample of Web3j with Android?
There is an example in the official docs, but I don't think it is not well self explanatory.
I'd like to see an example of wallet generating or smart contracts integration using Web3j & Android.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of sample? This is a pretty broad question and will most likely be flagged as too broad

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) Github documentation for [Web3j](https://web3j.io/) isn't a comprehensive tutorial but has helped me get running in the past.